# Confusion about probability

Tags: probability

I am really confused about a rather easy looking question.

Say we are to throw 2 dice and are looking to decide the probability of getting two number which has a difference of three.

What I am confused about is the following: considering the two dice identical (having the same colour) and unique (having different colour) seems to give me different answers.

Let us start with the case when the dice are different, say have colour red and green. Then the number of possible outcomes are 6x6=36 and we get difference 3 between the two numbers in the following way (6,3), (5,2), (4,1), (1,4), (2,5), (3,6). We consider (6,3) and (3,6) different since the dice have different colour. This means that the possibility of having difference 3 is 6/36 that is 1/6.

Now to the case when the dice are identical. In this case we have  21=6+5+4+3+2+1 different outcomes of the throw since in this case (3,1) and (1,3) for example is "the same outcome". This way we can get difference 3 in the following outcomes (1,4), (2,5) and (3,6) which leads to 3/21=1/7.

Is my calculation wrong? Or if it is correct than why is this the case?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you take the sample space to be the 21 distinguishable outcomes with identical dice -- that is theoretically perfectly ok. However, the 21 outcomes are NOT EQUALLY LIKELY (the doubles have half the frequency of the non-doubles), and so you can NOT compute probabilities with that sample space by doing (size of event)/21. Rather you would do Pr(event) =(sum of frequencies in the event), which in this case is 1/18 + 1/18 + 1/18 = 1/6 as before.

Comment: @James hmmm, (5,5) seems to be different in the two cases I described. I dont know, could you explain more why is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the dice are identical, you *can* say there are 21 possible outcomes, but *those outcomes do not have the same probability*. The probability of throwing any given pair of *unequal* numbers, $\frac2{36}$, is twice that of throwing a given double ($\frac1{36}$). In effect, accepting only 21 outcomes in the identical-dice case is lumping some of the 36 outcomes of the distinct-dice case together.

With this in mind, the probability of getting a difference of 3 between the rolls is not $\frac17$ as you calculated, but $\frac6{36}=\frac16$ like in the distinct-dice case.

Comment: Ahh! I see! So it is the safest two always consider them differently coloured?

Comment: @mathemagic Yes, yes.

Comment: Thank You very much for the effort! I was disturbed by this for the past hour. Have a nice evening!